# How to obtain my own facebook feed using GraphAPI

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for an answer regarding of how to get the latests facebook feed of my own account and display it on a webpage (through use of JS - client side).

From what i was able to understand i need to get an access token to use the

```
https://graph.facebook.com/YYY/feed?limit=5&access_token=XXX
```

so i can obtain my latest messages.

The problem is that the access token has to be retrieved manually. Is there a way to get read only data using Graph API, or do i have to curl and parse the page?

Partial solution.

Use rss feed as folows:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=json&id=XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to generate an access token to fetch feed data from any user/page/etc.. Recommend using the Graph Explorer Tool to help get that token and learn more about the requests: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed&version=v2.0

With that access token, you'll be able to request the JSON using jQuery (or your preferred library) like so:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_FACEBOOK_ID/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN', function(data) {
    console.log(data); // Do something with the returned data
  });
});
```

Comment: But this access token is only valid for one hour. I wasn't able to find a way of how to increase the validity duration.